# Where is the non-negativity of $f$ being used in the proof of Harnack's Inequality?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am inserting a section of [MIT OCW notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-152-introduction-to-partial-differential-equations-fall-2011/lecture-notes/MIT18_152F11_lec_07.pdf) on Partial Differential Equations.

[image]

Where is the non-negativity of $f$ being used?

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two typos in the notes. The denominator should be $(R-|x|)^2$ instead of $R^2-|x|^2$. (The latter anyway doesn't make sense, as $R+|x|$ in the numerator could have been cancelled against it.) And $|x|-R\le|x-\sigma|$ should be $R-|x|\le|x-\sigma|$ (as $|x|\le R$).

Apart from that, the argument is correct. It uses the non-negativity of $f$ in concluding

$$
\frac{f(\sigma)}{|x-\sigma|^3}\le\frac{f(\sigma)}{\left(R-|x|\right)^3}
$$

from $R-|x|\le|x-\sigma|$.